# Return specific value in multivalued field in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to figure out how to return only the first, or second value in a multivalued field in PowerShell.

For example:

```
get-aduser -filter * -properties * | select proxyaddresses
```

This will return all the proxyaddreses for all users - but I just want the first or second value in the field. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated to include Ryan's comment below.

You can use the first option of the Select-Object module (select is an alias).

```
# This will get the first 2 elements from whatever you pipe into the module
$x | Select-Object -first 2
```

For you query, you can just add the option to your existing select clause

```
get-aduser -filter * -properties * | select proxyaddresses -first 2
```

Other options include getting the last x elements, skipping the first x elements, etc. 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx

Comment: `select` is an alias of `Select-Object`.  Rather than calling it twice, you can combine the `[-Property]` and `-first` parameters into one command.  `get-aduser -filter * -properties | select proxyaddresses -first 2`